# How to insert multiple queries in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

For an example..inserting two queries at the same time and emphasizing that it has different table name..

```
INSERT INTO customer (Name, City) VALUES ("soyan","Naga City");
INSERT INTO employee (Name, Occupation) VALUES ("employee", "Supervisor" );
```

Comment: you can do it directly in database, there will no issue.

Comment: @Dharmeshpatel I'm planning to use those 4 rows by inserting a string in 4 of my textfield form(html) and when I hit submit it will eventually store my data to the databer

Comment: You can do it with no issue, as Dharmesh suggested.